# Redux Reducer won't set boolean object property

Tags: reactjs, redux, reducers

I have Redux reducer that works, except of a boolean variable that is not set. The code:

```
const GameBoardReducer = function(state, action) {  
  if( state === undefined ) {
    let state = { 
      rows: BOARD_ROWS,
      cols: BOARD_COLS,
      width: Math.min( document.body.clientWidth * 0.9, 1184 ),
      board: [],
      running: false,
      framesPerSec: 5,
    }
    for( var i=0 ; i<BOARD_ROWS ; i++ ) {
      state.board.push([]);
      for( var j=0 ; j<BOARD_COLS ; j++ ) {
        state.board[i].push(Math.random()<0.15? FIELD_ALIVE: FIELD_DEAD);
      }
    }   
    return state;
  }

  switch(action.type) {
  case SET_BOARD_ACTION:    
    return { ...state, board: action.payload };
  case RUN_ACTION:
    console.log("RunAction:", action.payload);
    return { ...state, running: action.payload };
  }

  return state;
}
```

The console shows

> RunAction: true

But the value in the container: `this.props.gameBoard.running` is still false.

Why?

The full pen: http://codepen.io/lafisrap/pen/yMZyXw

Comment: And the life game is running and stopping as it should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pen, you're holding a reference to the gameboard in `setInterval` and checking that to see if it's running, rather than checking the gameboard in this.props. Try these changes:

```
this.state = {
      interval: setInterval(() => this.calcNextGeneration(), ms)      
    };

calcNextGeneration() {
    console.log("calcNextGeneration", this.props.gameBoard.running);
    if( !this.props.gameBoard.running ) return;
...
```